# How can I move files to different directories depending on their contents?

Tags: shell, files, find, file-management

I have many files which contain a string like this:

```
/databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_piler/SRR6237661_chrm.fasta: N putative CRISPR arrays found
```

Where the `N` is a number that can be either `0` or greater. I need to move all files where the `N` is `0` to the directory `Sans_crispr` and all files where `N` is greater than `0` to the directory `Avec_crispr`.

I can also see with `ls` that all files where no CRISPR was found (those where `N` is `0`) are smaller than 3355 bytes, so maybe that can be used.

I tried this:

```
find . -name "*.out" -type 'f' -size -5k -exec mv {} /databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_piler/Dossier_fasta_chrm_sortie_pilercr/Sans_Crispr/ \;
```

But for all my files I have this

```
mv: cannot move './SRR5273182_chrm.fasta.fa-pilercr.out' to '/databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_piler/Dossier_fasta_chrm_sortie_pilercr/Sans-Crispr/': Not a directory
```

I tried some `for f in ...do done` or `if then fi`. I tried with `grep` for the pattern `' 0 putative CRISPR arrays found'`
But none of them worked, always an error or I didn't find what I want.

This is an example of my files:

[image]

And this is the contents:
With Crispr

```
Help on reading this report
===========================

This report has three sections: Detailed, Summary by Similarity and Summary by Position.

The detailed section shows each repeat in each putative CRISPR array.

The summary sections give one line for each array.

An 'array' is a contiguous sequence of CRISPR repeats looking like this:

    REPEAT Spacer REPEAT Spacer REPEAT ... Spacer REPEAT

Within one array, repeats have high similarity and spacers are, roughly speaking, unique within a window around the array. In a given array, each repeat has a similar length, and each spacer has a similar length. With default parameters, the algorithm allows a fair amount of variability in order to maximize sensitivity. This may allow identification of inactive ("fossil") arrays, and may in rare cases also induce false positives due to other classes of repeats such as microsatellites, LTRs and arrays of RNA genes.


Columns in the detailed section are:

  Pos               Sequence position, starting at 1 for the first base.   Repeat            Length of the repeat.   %id               Identity with the consensus sequence.   Spacer            Length of spacer to the right of this repeat.   Left flank        10 bases to the left of this repeat.   Repeat            Sequence of this repeat.
                      Dots indicate positions where this repeat
                      agrees with the consensus sequence below.   Spacer            Sequence of spacer to the right of this repeat,
                      or 10 bases if this is the last repeat.

The left flank sequence duplicates the end of the spacer for the preceding repeat; it is provided to facilitate visual identification of cases where the algorithm does not correctly identify repeat endpoints.

At the end of each array there is a sub-heading that gives the average repeat length, average spacer length and consensus sequence.

Columns in the summary sections are:

  Array             Number 1, 2 ... referring back to the detailed report.   Sequence          FASTA label of the sequence. May be truncated.   From              Start position of array.   To           End position of array.   # copies          Number of repeats in the array.   Repeat            Average repeat length.   Spacer            Average spacer length.   +                 +/-, indicating orientation relative to first array in group.   Distance          Distance from previous array.   Consensus         Consensus sequence.

In the Summary by Similarity section, arrays are grouped by similarity of their consensus sequences. If consensus sequences are sufficiently similar, they are aligned to each other to indicate probable relationships between arrays.

In the Summary by Position section, arrays are sorted by position within the input sequence file.

The Distance column facilitates identification of cases where a single array has been reported as two adjacent arrays. In such a case, (a) the consensus sequences will be similar or identical, and (b) the distance will be approximately a small multiple of the repeat length + spacer length.

Use the -noinfo option to turn off this help. Use the -help option to get a list of command line options.

pilercr v1.06 By Robert C. Edgar

/databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_piler/SRR2177954_chrm.fasta: 1 putative CRISPR arrays found.



DETAIL REPORT



Array 1
>SRR2177954.k141_500270 flag=1 multi=9.2309 len=7453

       Pos  Repeat     %id  Spacer  Left flank    Repeat                                  Spacer
==========  ======  ======  ======  ==========    ====================================    ======
        66      36   100.0      25  CAGAAGTATT    ....................................    CTCACACACGCTGATGCAGACAACA
       127      36   100.0      26  GCAGACAACA    ....................................    GCGAGAGCAGGGATTTGGAACGTAAT
       189      36   100.0      26  GGAACGTAAT    ....................................    ATGTTGATGGAAAAACTCCCACAGAC
       251      36   100.0          TCCCACAGAC    ....................................    ACTGAATGTG
==========  ======  ======  ======  ==========    ====================================
         4      36              25                ATCTACAAAAGTAGAAATTTTATAGAGGTATTTGGC


SUMMARY BY SIMILARITY



Array          Sequence    Position      Length  # Copies  Repeat  Spacer  +  Consensus
=====  ================  ==========  ==========  ========  ======  ======  =  =========
    1  SRR2177954.k141_          66         221         4      36      25  +  ATCTACAAAAGTAGAAATTTTATAGAGGTATTTGGC



SUMMARY BY POSITION



>SRR2177954.k141_500270 flag=1 multi=9.2309 len=7453

Array          Sequence    Position      Length  # Copies  Repeat  Spacer    Distance  Consensus
=====  ================  ==========  ==========  ========  ======  ======  ==========  =========
    1  SRR2177954.k141_          66         221         4      36      25              ATCTACAAAAGTAGAAATTTTATAGAGGTATTTGGC
```

Without Crispr

```
Help on reading this report
===========================

This report has three sections: Detailed, Summary by Similarity
and Summary by Position.

The detailed section shows each repeat in each putative
CRISPR array.

The summary sections give one line for each array.

An 'array' is a contiguous sequence of CRISPR repeats
looking like this:

    REPEAT Spacer REPEAT Spacer REPEAT ... Spacer REPEAT

Within one array, repeats have high similarity and spacers
are, roughly speaking, unique within a window around the array.
In a given array, each repeat has a similar length, and each
spacer has a similar length. With default parameters, the
algorithm allows a fair amount of variability in order to
maximize sensitivity. This may allow identification of
inactive ("fossil") arrays, and may in rare cases also
induce false positives due to other classes of repeats
such as microsatellites, LTRs and arrays of RNA genes.


Columns in the detailed section are:

  Pos               Sequence position, starting at 1 for the first base.
  Repeat            Length of the repeat.
  %id               Identity with the consensus sequence.
  Spacer            Length of spacer to the right of this repeat.
  Left flank        10 bases to the left of this repeat.
  Repeat            Sequence of this repeat.
                      Dots indicate positions where this repeat
                      agrees with the consensus sequence below.
  Spacer            Sequence of spacer to the right of this repeat,
                      or 10 bases if this is the last repeat.

The left flank sequence duplicates the end of the spacer for the preceding
repeat; it is provided to facilitate visual identification of cases
where the algorithm does not correctly identify repeat endpoints.

At the end of each array there is a sub-heading that gives the average
repeat length, average spacer length and consensus sequence.

Columns in the summary sections are:

  Array             Number 1, 2 ... referring back to the detailed report.
  Sequence          FASTA label of the sequence. May be truncated.
  From              Start position of array.
  To                End position of array.
  # copies          Number of repeats in the array.
  Repeat            Average repeat length.
  Spacer            Average spacer length.
  +                 +/-, indicating orientation relative to first array in group.
  Distance          Distance from previous array.
  Consensus         Consensus sequence.

In the Summary by Similarity section, arrays are grouped by similarity of their
consensus sequences. If consensus sequences are sufficiently similar, they are
aligned to each other to indicate probable relationships between arrays.

In the Summary by Position section, arrays are sorted by position within the
input sequence file.

The Distance column facilitates identification of cases where a single
array has been reported as two adjacent arrays. In such a case, (a) the
consensus sequences will be similar or identical, and (b) the distance
will be approximately a small multiple of the repeat length + spacer length.

Use the -noinfo option to turn off this help.
Use the -help option to get a list of command line options.

pilercr v1.06
By Robert C. Edgar

/databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_piler/ERR1544006_chrm.fasta: 0 putative CRISPR arrays found.
```

Thanks your for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate over the files, and `grep` for `: 0 putative CRISPR regions`. If the `grep` finds a match, move the file:

```
mkdir -p Sans_crispr Avec_crispr
for file in *pilercr.out; do
    if grep -q ': 0 putative CRISPR arrays' "$file"; then
        mv "$file" Sans_crispr
    else
        mv "$file" Avec_crispr
    fi
done
```

The `-q` flag to `grep` tells it not to print any output, but it will still exit with a failed status if no match is found and with success if a match is found. So here we use that to move the files to the appropriate folder.

The reason you were getting this error:

```
mv: cannot move './SRR5273182_chrm.fasta.fa-pilercr.out' to '/databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_piler/Dossier_fasta_chrm_sortie_pilercr/Sans-Crispr/': Not a directory
```

Is because the directory `/databis/defontis/Dossier_fasta_chrm_avec_piler/Dossier_fasta_chrm_sortie_pilercr/Sans-Crispr/` doesn't exist. This is why the first command in the little script above is `mkdir -p Sans_crispr Avec_crispr` which means "create the directories Sans_crispr and Avec_crispr unless if they don't already exist".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the speed.

Comment: problem : they all go on Avec_crispr :/

Comment: @Fraizu please edit your question as I asked and show us an example file with CRISPR and one without CRISPR. We need the _actual_ file to be able to test properly. Maybe the other files also have `: 0 putative CRISPR regions` on one of their lines.

Comment: Also, @Fraizu, your `find` command would work but you need the right directory name. Your question mentioned `Sans_crispr` but your command was using a directory called `Sans-crispr` instead.

Comment: I edited my question with new image I hope it will help u

Comment: @Fraizu no, the whole problem is that you are giving images! Please do what I asked and copy/paste the actual file into your question. I cannot use an image.

Comment: Ho shit for the find's command i didn't see it thanks but finally the better the best would be to check with the line in grep because if I sort by size it is not very "clean".

Comment: @Fraizu see updated answer. I had used the wrong string: I was searching for `CRISPR regions` and not `CRISPR arrays`. It should work now.

Comment: I re try (sorry to not see it too) but again the same problem they all go on Avec_crispr

Comment: @Fraizu OK,  so take one of the files that HAS CRISPR data and run this: `grep ' : 0 putative CRISPR arrays' $file` (where $file is the file with crispr). What is the output? –

Comment: Nothing, no output and I have same with file without crispr

Comment: When i do this `grep ' 0 putative CRISPR arrays found' ` I see all of the without crispr so all which have the ' : 0 putative CRISPR arrays'
But if i put a file after : nothing

Comment: @Fraizu Argh! I had an extra space there. I was searching for `<space>: 0 putative...` and I should have been searching for `: 0 putative...`. Sorry! Please try the updated answer again.

Comment: It worked !!!! So thanks :o

Comment: Great, @Fraizu! If one of the answers here solved your issue (feel free to wait for other answers in case someone has a better solution), please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Yes i did 
Thanks again :D Have a nice day ! :D

Comment: @Fraizu one last thing. You might be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se]. This question isn't really about bioinformatics, and it is fine here, but sometimes the details will depend on the file formats you are using so [bioinformatics.se] can be a better place to ask. Good luck!

Comment: ho yeah really thanks u